# How can I redirect a page with a 301 header in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, header

How can I redirect

```
example.com/script.php?id=567
```

to

```
example.com/script2.php?id=5677&something=anotherthing&something2=anotherthing2
```

in php using a header 301 redirect?

Comment: in php or mod_rewrite? choose one pls

Comment: I'm guessing he wants PHP since it's tagged that way.

Comment: yes,this what i wanted... my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the file `script.php` then you can add the following code on top:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

//Get your extra params from the database if needed...

header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: http://example.com/script2.php?id='.$id.'&something=anotherthing&something2=anotherthing2'); //Append params retrieved from database here.
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The code itself is simple:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/script.php?id=567'){
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://example.com/script2.php?id=5677&something=anotherthing&something2=anotherthing2');
    die();
}
?>
```

You can also use [$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to get the hostname `example.com`. And you also have to make sure your script doesn't have any output before calling `header()`.

Comment: ok but 567 was only an example... that is a variable...                                                             (my bad that i have not specified)

Comment: What do you want to redirect, where, by what match? @Col. Shrapnel might have been right. If your situation is not PHP specific, you should consider using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: well... for example 576 it could be a id from a database (and i have more) i need to redirect it using php.

Comment: so you have `$id=576` ... and you want to specifically redirect to `script2.php?id={$id}7&otherparams` ? If not, post the redirect link or map or smth

Comment: i've tried to add `$the_id=$_REQUEST['id'];` but the script doesn't work anymore       script2.php?id=$the_id&otherparams

Comment: scrip2.php doesn't work anymore? are you sure you're passing the corect link ?